# Sending bulk emails with unique attachments (service or java or api)

Tags: java, email, email-attachments, bulk

**Hello Stackers :-) ,**

I have been asked to send out approx. 2000 emails with unique attachments to unique email addresses.

**Background:** 
Users registered for an event and I am supposed to send out their tickets with unique QR code and seating.

**What I have:**

- List of the email addresses
- Generated attachements (JPG, 400kb in size each)

**What is no problem for me:**

- Use any external paid service for this
- Code if needed in JAVA (there is where my skill ends)

I am looking for any kind of solution that is reliable and not that problematic to implement. I have very little knowledge of email-tech background. Ends with POP3 / SMTP :)

Could I please ask you for any tips or tricks on this? Anyone here has struggled before with something similar please? I would be greatly thankful for any useful info since Im totally lost

**Thank you**

**Oliver**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dear all,**

https://www.mailgun.com/

with all their API helped me do what I wanted.

**Closing this question.
Oliver**